# PHP: preg_match amazon wishlist

Tags: php

i have tried this code on localhost to extract items from amazon wishlist:

```
$text = file_get_contents(trim($wishlist_link));

if (preg_match('~<form method="post" name="editItems" style="display: inline; margin: 0;" [^>]*>(.*?)</form>~si', $text, $body)) {}
```

It works fine but when I tried the same code for online domain, it was working only for 10 items for amazon wishlist

Comment: can u explain in more details thanks

Comment: Can you provide the html source code you want to match so i can verify your regex (12 or 20 items from the wishlist)?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/wishlist/3V4Y6SXZRSBS2/ref=topnav_lists_1